# What controls back-pressure in the Reactive Mongodb driver?

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot, kotlin, project-reactor, aws-documentdb

I have hard time understanding how the back-pressure mechanism in the Reactive Mongodb driver actually works. Say for example that I have a reactive flow with a Flux with many items that looks up stuff in the database, something along the lines of:

```
            .map { doSomeMapping(it) }
            .flatMap { repository.findById(it) }
```

What mechanism is used to avoid that the database isn't overloaded with requests when the `flatMap` executes, especially if there are a lot of similar calls in a long-running flow? The Reactor thread pool puts some limit of the number of concurrent requests as far as I understand, but does the driver take into account e.g. some connection pool value to limit the number of operations? In our particular case we have issues with too many cursors being open but it's far from easy to see how this can be limited, other than using e.g. a `concatMap()` to run operations sequentially instead.

Comment: flatMap has an overloaded version you can use to set the concurrency level, other than that you can use resilience4j for bulkhead and rate limiting

Comment: Interesting tip @MartinTarjányi - will definitely give that a try.

Comment: Does the driver support backpressure in the first place? And where in your flow is the concurrency happening?

Comment: @abetteroliver According to the documentation (https://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver-reactivestreams/1.13/), "...providing asynchronous stream processing with back pressure in line with the Reactive Streams specification". We have multiple `flatMap()` class in our application running db-queries and they are executed concurrently as far as I understand.

Comment: do you find any solution for your problem? @ErikFinnman

Comment: @ZahraHosseini Sorry for the late reply - when ended up re-writing the code to manually set the concurrency level using overloaded version of `flatMap()` as suggested in a comment above.

Comment: you disable concurrent execution, right?

Comment: in my case this issue solved by setting limitRate on flux. ( i insert data to mongo from a flux. infact both side are reactive. producer and consumer. @ErikFinnman